# Testing Fetching Strategies with Hibernate annotations

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, intellij-idea

I would like to test different annotations on two related classes in my Spring boot project. The IDE is Intellij with gradle as the build tool.

I understand that by default `@ManyToOne and @OneToOne` are fetched eagerly. I want to see the difference this makes when I override it.

When testing this in the browser using the controller it is both time consuming to see results and Jackson serialises the responses.

**ENTITIES**

Mechanic Visit

```java
    @Entity
    @Data
    @Table(name="MechanicVisit")
    public class MechanicVisit {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
        private Long id;

        @JsonManagedReference
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
        private Car car;
```

Car

```java
    @Entity
    @Data
    public class Car {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
    
        @JsonBackReference
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "car")
        private List<MechanicVisit> listMechanicVisit = new ArrayList<>();
        //others
```

And my manual method to get a MechanicVisit on the repository (which should not get a car):

```
@Query("SELECT m FROM MechanicVisit m WHERE m.id = :id")
Optional <MechanicVisit> getOneManually(@Param("id") Long id);
```

How can I quickly test the effects of different fetching strategies like `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` in the Spring generated test structure at /src/main/java without starting and stopping the server all the time?

I note it has generated a test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
class CarApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

Comment: Hibernate has test cases templates: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/tree/main/orm/hibernate-orm-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to instantiate Entity Manager manually, set a breakpoint in debug mode and then evaluate various queries:

**Repository**

```
public class MechanicVisitServiceImpl implements MechanicVisitService {
private final MechanicVisitRepository mechanicVisitRepository;

@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;

//other queries
```

Then in Intellij when your code hits a breakpoint you can `CTRL-F8` to evaulate expressions like:

```
entityManager.createQuery("SELECT m FROM MechanicVisit m WHERE m.id=1").getResultList()
```